# AngularJS ng-model and ng-checked radio button slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update an ng-model when a radio button is checked. Although my radio buttons are actually images and my radio buttons are being updated by a function using arrows to cycle through them.

For some reason my $scope.transaction only updates when I actually click the image rather than changing the image using the arrows. Any idea why?

[image: My UI]

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts" 
     ng-show="showContactID == {{contact.contact_id}}">
    <div class="radio text-center">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" 
                   value="{{contact.contact_id}}" 
                   ng-checked="showContactID == {{contact.contact_id}}"
                   ng-model="transaction.contact_id">

            <img src="public/img/profiles/{{contact.contact_id}}.jpg" 
                 class="img-circle" 
                 height="150">
            <h4>{{contact.contact_name}}</h4>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a class="btn" 
           ng-click="changeContact('prev')">
         <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a class="btn" 
           ng-click="changeContact('next')">
         <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.transaction .form-group.contacts input {
    display: none;
}

.transaction .form-group.contacts .radio {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.changeContact = function(which){

    var currentContactID = $scope.showContactID;
    var newContactID = 0;

    if(which){

        angular.forEach($scope.contacts, function(contact, key){

            if(contact.contact_id == currentContactID){

                if($scope.contacts[which == 'next' ? key + 1 : key - 1] == undefined){

                    newContactID = $scope.contacts[which == 'next' ? 0 : $scope.contacts.length - 1].contact_id;

                }
                else{

                    newContactID = $scope.contacts[which == 'next' ? key + 1 : key - 1].contact_id;

                }

            }

        });

        $scope.showContactID = newContactID;

    }

};
```

Comment: What does the transaction.contact_id do? Anyways. The problem here is that you are trying the bind many input-values to a single value in the controller. I was trying the give you an example solution but as said before. I dont get the purpose of the transaction.contact_id

Comment: transaction.contact_id is a foreign key in my database that links many transactions to one contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you calls `changeContact` function , also update `transaction.contact_id` value with `newContactID` in same function.

Comment: Thanks @shivali. Worked like a charm! Although I'm unsure as to whether this is just a quick fix? The model should be updated when the contact changes as we are updating the radio button to "checked." Or am I getting the wrong idea here?

Comment: No,Model value cant be updated when you changed checked property.For that you have to update update your model value, and radio button which have same value as model value, that one be selected. If you remove checked property from this,still it worked fine. For Better understanding see please this example http://jsfiddle.net/Shivali/qcm3nh4r/.